# Ingress to redirect to service from LB ip

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm trying to create an `Ingress` rule to redirect requests from LoadBalancer to Service.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hostlessendpoint
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hostless
        backend:
          serviceName: node-red
          servicePort: 1880
```

The above yaml script is supposed to redirect all requests from `https://LOAD_BALANCER_IP/hostless` to `node-red` on port `1880`

If I try to request the above URL, I got an error `Cannot GET /hostless`. Requesting the root gives `404 page not found`.

I can access my services with the direct URL (eg. `http://LOAD_BALANCER_IP:1880` will redirect to Node-red service).

Service yaml looks like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: node-red
  name: node-red
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "1880"
      port: 1880
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1880
  selector:
    app: node-red
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

How to use `ingress` to reach a service whereas a custom port ?

Comment: Thats because your service needs to expose a /hostless route as well. Whats happening is that the ingress is calling node-red:1880/hostless that may not exist.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what's happening ! How to strip the prefix ? Using `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip` does not seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to make it works !

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: "kube-system-traefik-stripprefix@kubernetescrd"
  name: traefik-all
  namespace: partner
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-demo
          servicePort: 2222
      - path: /node
        backend:
          serviceName: node-red
          servicePort: 1880
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: traefik-stripprefix
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  stripPrefixRegex:
    regex:
      - "/[^/]+"
```

I use a middleware to remove the prefix as K3S Traefik does not support the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation.

With the above code, all trafic from `LOAD_BALANCER_IP/*` will be redirected to `nginx-demo:2222` service. All trafic from `LOAD_BALANCER_IP/node/*` will be redicted to `node-red:1880` service.

I hope this could help someone !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a rewrite-target annotation, which will effectively rewrite `/hostless` requests to `/`, i.e. `http://LOAD_BALANCER_IP:1880/hostless` externally to `http://node-red:1880` internally.

For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: hostlessendpoint
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hostless(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: node-red
          servicePort: 1880
```

See [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), assuming you are using Nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Traefik 2.4.8 with K3S. There is no `rewrite-target` field.